# Automatically adjusting the HTML table column

Tags: css, html, angular

I am trying to map a matrix in the following Mockup into a table. The matrix will be implemented as a Angular 5 Component.

[image]

The values of cells are of type number and can be very different. The following table show the cell with two-digit number.

[image]

If one cell in the table has a eight-digit number the table look like this:

[image]

The table is generated by Typescript as follow:

```html
<table *ngFor="let table of atService.mockData" >
  <tr *ngFor="let row of table.data; let i = index"  >
    <div>
    <td *ngFor="let cell of row" [ngStyle]= "{'background-color': cell.flag== '0' ? 'yellow' : (cell.flag== '1' ? 'red' : '') }">
     {{cell.value}}
    </td>
  </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table td,
 table tr {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

How can I adjust the table columns automatically?

Comment: Can you share your markup and styles. It would be great if you share it as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Use CSS Grid it works perfect with your requirement,moreover its damn easy. refer this https://github.com/wesbos/css-grid

Comment: It seems you're not using a <table> to represent a table... I'm not sure why but that would defeinitely help. Table tag is not forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set table style width:100% then table width automatically adjust with column content

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS section of the table, make sure that width is 100% and table layout is auto.

```
 table-layout: auto;
 width: 100%;
```